# How do you pass a A HREF value from a php function?

Tags: php, html, mysql

So with this code we pull in some data from a mysql database with php.  Then everything works, except the a href formatting (for bootstrap). This code is really long, so I tried to get the parts that pertain to the problem.

The drop down works great when it isn't part of this function and all the data pulls through like it should.  The function somehow throws out the bootstrap class, id, role, etc. in a href.

```
function menu_element_builder($values) {
$links = '';
foreach($values as $value) {
            if(is_array($value['args'])) {
              $links .= (!empty($value['href']))?'
/* this a href part doesn't pull through the ID, Role, data-toggle, or class */           
                  <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary" href="'.$value['href'].'">'.$value['name'].'<span class="caret"></span>
              </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">':'
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    '.$value['name'].'
</li> //it has more than this, keeping it simple
</ul>
return $links;
}

(an array of $link values are listed)
//This is part of case break statements to know which icons to  load
$themed_elements = menu_element_builder($link_values);

<html>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">

  <?php echo $themed_elements; ?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

old code

```
function menu_element_builder($values) {
$links = '';
foreach($values as $value) {
if(is_array($value['args'])) {
  $links .= (!empty($value['href']))?'<li><a class="dir" href="'.$value['href'].'">'.$value['name'].'</a><ul>':'<li><span class="dir">'.$value['name'].'</span></li></ul>';

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".dir").click(function(){
    //this.addclass('ul.dropdown li:hover');
});
});
```

Comment: You're absolutely sure that the code generates properly with the function?

Comment: I was looking at the code and there actually is a javascript function that the old code called for the old style drop down..   I think it is the problem.

Comment: I just put it up for you to see.  The old drop down works.  i just wanted to update it to bootstrap.